# Typical Naming Conventions for Python Directories in Packages

Tags: python, directory, naming-conventions

**The Question**
I would like to know if there is a standard convention for the naming of Python directories that plan to be imported as a module.  Meaning the directory contains a blank `__init__.py`

**Background**
Up until recently I have given it little thought and named solely based on what made sense at the file system level.  What got me in trouble is that what made sense at the file system level also made sense for other developers' standalone modules.  Consider the following directory:

```
+ drivers
    + prologix  
        - __init__.py
        - driver_a.py
        - driver_b.py
    + visa
        - __init__.py  
        - driver_a.py
        - driver_b.py
    __init__.py
    ringout.py <-- simple file to ring-out the drivers
```

While this worked fine when ringing out the prologix's drivers, I ran into an issue when trying to import my visa drivers as well as pyVisa's 'visa' module.  It was very easy to diagnose the problem, but the fix to rename my visa driver's folder to 'visa_dir' makes the code more difficult to read (IMO).

```
import drivers.visa
```

vs

```
import drivers.visa_dir
```

**Is there a better way to handle this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each module's namespace is unique, so even if you have two modules named `visa` as long as you avoid importing them into the same namespace with the same name you won't have any problems. I tend to prefer absolute imports:

```
import drivers.visa
import pyVisa.visa
```

Or you could also use `as`:

```
from drivers import visa
from pyVisa import visa as pyvisa
```

...etc. Just be careful how you import things. I'd prefer (as an end-user) that you structure your modules logically within your package and not worry about pre-mangling them for me.

Comment: To add to this, see [this blog post](http://griddlenoise.blogspot.com/2006/10/namespace-packages-in-python.html) and [PEP 221](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/).

Comment: +1 for absolute imports I didn't really think about that.  This will show some of my newness to Python, but what about built in modules?  Is there a similar way to import them in the same fashion? Take math for an example (one of the more generic ones I could think of).

Comment: Sure you can use the same import tricks on the standard library.

Comment: In the use case from X import math.  What is 'X' ? :)

Comment: A package or a module available on your PYTHONPATH as `X`. If you don't already have a `math` in your namespace you won't have any problems. Here's another article to check out: http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath